# Giving NumericUpDown Events in Flow Layout Panel (C#)

Tags: c#, event-handling, flowlayoutpanel

I'm using the following code to generate NumericUpDown's inside of a FlowLayoutPanel but I can't figure out how to add a Value Changed event handler.

```
        string numericUpDownText = "captchaNumericUpDown";
        NumericUpDown newNumericUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
        newNumericUpDown.Name = textboxID.ToString() + numericUpDownText;
        newNumericUpDown.Width = 50;
        itemFlowPanel.Controls.Add(newNumericUpDown);
```

I want all of them to do the same thing, but I'm not sure how to trigger the event. I've tried the following, but it didn't work either.

```
newNumericUpDown.ValueChanged = sylladexUpdate(sender, e);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your code inside "ValueChanged" event handler.

```
NumericUpDown newNumericUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
newNumericUpDown.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(newNumericUpDown_ValueChanged);
```

And your event handler-

```
private void NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
    sylladexUpdate(sender, e); 
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can automatically create an event handler for each NumericUpDown created?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer!! It may help others!

Comment: Yep, had to wait 15 minutes before I could mark it.